# How do I optimise my function to move past an X Y destination

Tags: javascript, math, coordinates

For anyone interested, this is a scenario on codingame.com for an optimisation puzzle called code vs zombies.

I was working on a code challenge which focusses on a player having to move towards a destination. If the co-ordinates for the destination are close, the player will move more slowly towards the position, as the speed is dictated by the position difference from the player to the destination. To solve this issue and make the player always move as fast as possible (the speed logic is outside of my control in this situation) I created a function.

```
let p = parseInt
    let speedup = (destination,playerPosition) =>{
        let [destX,destY] = destination.split(" ");
        let [playerX,playerY] = playerPosition.split(" ");
        destX = p(destX);destY=p(destY);playerX=p(playerX);playerY=p(playerY)
        let [xDist,yDist] = [destX-playerX,destY-playerY]
        let i=1
        do {
             if ((xDist*i)+playerX<0 || (yDist*i)+playerY<0 || xDist> 20000 || yDist > 20000){
                xDist = (xDist*(i-1))+playerX;
                yDist = (yDist*(i-1))+playerY;
                return xDist + " " + yDist;
             }
             else if(i==19){
                xDist = (xDist*i)+playerX;
                yDist = (yDist*i)+playerY; 
                return xDist + " " + yDist;
             }
             i++
          } while (i<20);
    }
```

The function takes in two parameters. Both parameters have an X and a Y position inside a string, like so:

```
destination = "3000 5800"
playerPosition = "6000 7800"
```

The X Y map goes does not have any negatives in it, so it moves from top left 0,0.

If I pass a negative value back into the movement, for example "-2000 3000" the program will crash (again, this bit is outside of my control in this scenario).

So to break this down, I've split the array into the individual variables, written a loop to  multiply the velocity and then added the player position to it. each time I check if X or Y are less than 0 and if they are, I use the previous result.

The code seems to work, but it's pretty clunky I think, and I'm sure there are better ways to do it.

Edit - for clarity on what is being returned.

the return is a string which has an X and a Y co-ordinate with a space for example:

```
return "20 300"
```

this is telling the player to go to the X co-ordinate 20, and the Y co-ordinate 300

in terms of the speed, the input of this return is at a set rate, so say it's once per second. So if I tell my player at 100,100 to move to 99,99 the player will do it very slowly. It will take the entire second to move a distance of 1,1, that said if I tell the player to move to 1,1, he will move in the same direction, but much faster.

the variable I am passing in is an intersection between two points, I want the player to travel to that destination fast (and even move past it) regardless of how close it is.

[image: example]

Comment: It's very hard to understand what your code is supposed to be doing. Could you explain what this function is supposed to return?

Comment: What are the criteria for the function? What's the "speed" the player is supposed to move? Is there a limit to the distance or inputs?

Comment: I've added information to clarify both points

Comment: what is `p()` doing?

Comment: p is shorthand for the parseInt function - sorry I missed that! it's outside the code example @Thomas

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to optimize?

Comment: even with your code and your explanation I don't understand what point you're trying to return. You pass in a start point and indicate a direction through the second point. That defines a ray with an infinite amount of points on it. But which one are you looking for? Then you count to 19 and do some weird *exponential* math :confused: *exponential, that's probably why you need the checks to abort when dist explodes `xDist> 20000 || yDist > 20000`. But I still don't get which target point you'Re looking for.

Comment: I indicate a co-ordinate with the second parameter, the original target destination. the altered target destination I want to be beyond that original point as shown by the green circle. I just want to make sure it's far away enough from the player to ensure the player travels at maximum speed, if the original target is too close, the player walks slowly. @Thomas

Comment: So what's maximum speed? Can you return numbers as large as you want?

Comment: I don't know the maximum speed, the code challenge doesn't go into that, but it seems if I am inputting a distance of around 2000 it looks to be max speed. I can return a co-ordinate up to int value, but positives only. so if for example I'm at 10,10, and the destination is 5,5, the furthest point I can travel to would be 0,0. @GuillaumeBrunerie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still feel like we are missing some information because it is a pretty weird problem, but here is a solution (completely untested).

From what I understand, we want a point with integer coordinates on the line from `playerPosition` to `destination`. The point should have non-negative coordinates and (if possible) at least at a distance of 2000 from `playerPosition`.

```js
const minDistance = 2000;
const parse = (str) => str.split(" ").map(s => parseInt(s));
const speedup = (destination, playerPosition) => {
  const [playerX, playerY] = parse(playerPosition);
  const [destX, destY] = parse(destination);
  const [dx, dy] = [destX - playerX, destY - playerY];
  // Now we want to return the player position + a certain number of times [dx, dy]
  // First we compute the amount of times we need to multiply it
  const dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  if (dist == 0) {
    return `${playerX} ${playerY}`; // We are already arrived
  }
  let steps = Math.ceil(minDistance / dist);
  // Then we deal with the non-negative stuff by limiting the amount of steps if it would result in a negative position
  if (dx < 0) {
    steps = Math.min(steps, Math.floor(-playerX / dx));
  }
  if (dy < 0) {
    steps = Math.min(steps, Math.floor(-playerY / dy));
  }
  // We are done
  return `${playerX + steps * dx} ${playerY + steps * dy}`;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to dissect this a little more, but based on my testing of the output, it's doing exactly what I want it to do. It seems a lot cleaner and I like your parse function for changing everything to an int in one go too. Thank you. It is a bit of a strange scenario.